# Convert TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds to long

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I have some `DateTime` variable, and I want to use `System.Threading.Timer` to wait until this time arrive. If time is in the past I want the timer to tick immediately.

**The problem is** `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds` is `double` and timer due time biggest type is`long`.

I've tried to max the due-time to `long.MaxValue` using this code:

```
DateTime someUtcTime;
// Max due time to long.MaxValue
double doubleDueTime = Math.Min(
    (double)long.MaxValue,
    someUtcTime.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMilliseconds);

// Avoid negative numbers
long dueTime = Math.Max(0L, (long)doubleDueTime);

_timer.Change(dueTime, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

but it turns out that **casting `long.MaxValue` to double and back to long result a negative number** (in unchecked code of curse). plz send me teh codez.

---

**Edit:** apparently, no matter which of [`Timer.Change`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.change.aspx) overload you use, they are all limited to 4294967294 (`UInt32.MaxValue - 1`) milliseconds.

---

### Solution:

cover both extreme cases (`someUtcTime = DateTime.MaxValue; UtcNow = DateTime.MinValue;` and vice versa).

```
const uint MAX_SUPPORTED_TIMEOUT = uint.MaxValue - 1; //0xfffffffe

DateTime someUtcTime;
double doubleDueTime = (someUtcTime - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMilliseconds;

// Avoid negative numbers
doubleDueTime = Math.Max(0d, doubleDueTime);

// Max due time to uint.MaxValue - 1
uint dueTime = (uint)Math.Min(MAX_SUPPORTED_TIMEOUT, doubleDueTime);
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `Math.Min((double)long.MaxValue` part of your code?

Comment: "plz send me teh codez." - hopefully that is humour!

Comment: @Gabe: dates too far in the future?

Comment: @Mitch, it looked like a simple 2 minutes task, but I can't manage to get it right. Frustration led me to humor. It's a way of saying: "How would you, my fellow scholars, would solve this conundrum?". I hope SO is not banning humor at all :)

Comment: You're worried about a timestamp 300 million years into the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `(DateTime.MaxValue - DateTime.MinValue).TotalMilliseconds` is 315537897600000 and `long.MaxValue` is 9223372036854775807 (`long` can represent a value 4 orders of magnitude larger than the largest possible number of milliseconds between any two `DateTime` values), you can *never* have a time too far in the future.

This will suffice:

```
DateTime someUtcTime;
// Max due time to long.MaxValue
double doubleDueTime = (someUtcTime - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalMilliseconds;

// Avoid negative numbers
long dueTime = Math.Max(0L, (long)doubleDueTime);

_timer.Change(dueTime, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

Comment: Good point mate. Although, as I edited, the limitation is `UInt32.MaxValue - 1`, so it work for [~50 days in the future](http://www.google.com/search?q=4294967294+ms+in+days). I'll just use this + @Marino's.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe just work with the Ticks property (Ticks are Long) and multiply by TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond (constant, 10,000 ticks per millisecond).

Comment: It sounds like it will work, but somehow it doesn't feel natural for me to use ticks for real world times. Maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 2):

```
Timespan timespan = someUtcTime.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow);
long time = timespan.TotalMilliseconds <= long.MaxValue ? (long)timespan.TotalMilliseconds : -1;

if (time == -1) {
 sorry.nocando();
}
else {
 just.doit();
}
```

BTW: with a long millisecond you can have a timespan of 292471208 years, I don't think your code will be used by then. There is possibility that the sun will already have expanded past mars and earth is no more :D

Comment: beware that I am assuming time on a positive  progression, hawking suggests that time could be even immaginary, or going backwards, so '-1' may be a possible time quantity :)

Answer (score 0):

Timers are designed to wait for intervals (typically shorter than 24 hours).

What is your intended use? A scheduler would typically have a list of events/tasks, and periodically every minute (maybe every second) check to see if any tasks need to be fired.

Perhaps something like [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) might be appropriate?

Comment: It is a kind of scheduler, but it is so light on features that I don't want to couple it with 3rd party libraries.